# What would happen if I swirl a bottle of water in the space station?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-fall, vortex

Right now I am swinging a bottle of water in a tight circular motion to form a vortex, the vortex will last quite a while after I stopped swinging it. The vortex will took the shape of a funnel in 1g at sea level, but if I were to repeat the same experiment in free fall (inside a space station) would the funnel shaped vortex appears if I let go of the bottle?

Comment: You can almost perfectly do this experiment in gravity by taking the partially full water bottle, putting it on its side, and rolling it across a table.

Answer (score 0):

Without gravity to pull the water towards the bottom of the bottle, it would stay along the entire length of the bottle.

Presumably the result would instead be a water layer flowing against  the circumference of the bottle, or if the swirling resulted in an uneven distribution of water, a "wave" or linear lump of water travelling along the circumference. In both cases the water would gradually transfer angular momentum to the bottle until both spun together around the axis. In the latter case the uneven mass distribution would cause a lot of wobbling.

Answer (score -2):

Just like for the spinning top, low gravity is equivalent to high angular velocity. Thus, without needing to be in freefall, you can check what happens by rotating the bottle faster. Intuitively, as gravity decreases (or angular velocity increases), the height of the funnel increases until it reaches the top. Asymptotically, you’d expect the shape of the water to be cylindrical shell (an empty cylinder, a water cylindrical shell and then the bottle when viewed radially).

Hope this helps.

Comment: downvoting. Have you ever heard something about Reynolds number?

Comment: Yes I have... However, since the funnel you usually see in this setup looks like the usual inverse funnel from an inviscid, potential flow, I would argue that for a first approximation it does not matter much.